# With html5 audio limitations on iOS, is it possible to play background music and sound effects at the same time?

Tags: ios, html, audio

I've been reading about [the limitations of html5 on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/using_html5_audio_video/device-specificconsiderations/device-specificconsiderations.html).

> Currently, all devices running iOS are limited to playback of a single audio or video stream at any time. Playing more than one video—side by side, partly overlapping, or completely overlaid—is not currently supported on iOS devices. Playing multiple simultaneous audio streams is also not supported. You can change the audio or video source dynamically, however. See “Replacing a Media Source Sequentially” for details.

Apparently I can only play one file at a time.  A common technique is to have one file, but combine all of the sounds you need into this one file and seek to the parts you want to play.  This is called an audio sprite.

But here's what's not clear to me: If I use an audio sprite, can I overlap it with itself?  For example, can I have the sound of a bullet while I'm playing background music?  Or, can I have the sound of two bullets firing simultaneously?

Comment: background music and sound effects on a site? ur going to make a lot of friends.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea it's a game

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Mobile Safari (http://caniuse.com/audio-api) support the Web Audio API, which supports simultaneous playback.

Check this demo on an iOS device: https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/TouchPad/index.html

Shameless plug for a simple wrapper: https://github.com/endemic/sona